# Is there a way of monitoring changes in visible clients list in awesome-wm?

Tags: awesome-wm

I know i can call screen:get_clients() in a loop to achieve this, but I'd like to do it asynchronously.
I've tried to use manage and unmanage signals, but this doesn't cover all scenarios eg. switching tags, moving clients to other tags and minimizing clients.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single signal for what you are asking, I think. So you will need to collect all the necessary signals yourself.

- switching tags: That's `property::selected` on the tag class
- moving clients to other tags: `tagged` and `untagged` signals on either clients or tags
- minimizing clients: `property::minimized`

The same approach, connecting to lots of signals, is also done in the code in AwesomeWM. For example, here is the tasklist's code: https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/blob/7a759432d3100ff6870e0b2b427e3352bf17c7cc/lib/awful/widget/tasklist.lua#L641-L676